# Arrow sign appearing in top bar after upgrading to OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos

After upgrading my Mac's OS to OS X El Capitan, an arrow sign appearing in top bar, Nothing happens whenever I click on this icon.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the icon is from VMware Fusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's VMWare Fusion. If you launch VMWare and go to Preferences, you can disable that menu item.